# Sum a subquery and group by customer info

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables something like the following:

```
Customer (CustomerID, AddressState)
Account (AccountID, CustomerID, OpenedDate)
Payment (AccountID, Amount)
```

The Payment table can contain multiple payments for an Account and a Customer can have multiple accounts.

What I would like to do is retrieve the total amount of all payments on a State by State and Month by Month basis. E.g.

```
Opened Date| State | Total
--------------------------
2009-01-01 |   CA  | 2,500
2009-01-01 |   GA  | 1,000
2009-01-01 |   NY  |   500
2009-02-01 |   CA  | 1,500
2009-02-01 |   NY  | 2,000
```

In other words, I'm trying to find out what States paid the most for each month. I'm only interested in the month of the OpenedDate but I get it as a date for processing afterwards. I was trying to retrieve all the data I needed in a single query.

I've been trying something along the lines of:

```
select
  dateadd (month, datediff(month, 0, a.OpenedDate), 0) as 'Date',
  c.AddressState as 'State',
  (
    select sum(x.Amount)
    from (
      select p.Amount
      from Payment p
      where p.AccountID = a.AccountID
    ) as x
  )
  from Account a
  inner join Customer c on c.CustomerID = a.CustomerID
  where ***
  group by
    dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, a.OpenedDate), 0),
    c.AddressState
```

The where clause includes some general stuff on the Account table.  The query won't work because the a.AccountID is not included in the aggregate function.

Am I approaching this the right way?  How can I retrieve the data I require in order to calculate which States' customers pay the most?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the data grouped by month, you need to group by month:

```
SELECT  AddressState, DATEPART(mm, OpenedDate), SUM(Amount)
FROM    Customer c
INNER JOIN Account a  ON a.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
INNER JOIN Payments p ON p.AccountID = a.AccountID
GROUP BY   AddressState, DATEPART(mm, OpenedDate)
```

This shows you the monthnumber (1-12) and the total amount per state. Note that this example doesn't include years: all amounts of month 1 are summed regardless of year. Add a datepart(yy, OpenedDate) if you like.

Comment: +1 Simple solution, could include a filter on the last half year or a group by on year.

Comment: I think I was over complicating it.  Using this solution and combining it with the dateadd(datediff()) and my where clause worked. See http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/09/10/group-by-month-sql.aspx if you want to know why I prefer the dateadd(datediff()) to group by month.

Answer (score 1):

> In other words, I'm trying to find out what States paid the most for each month

This one will select the most profitable state for each month:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  yr, mon, AddressState, amt, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY yr, mon, addressstate ORDER BY amt DESC) AS rn
        FROM    (
                SELECT  YEAR(OpenedDate) AS yr, MONTH(OpenedDate) AS mon, AddressState, SUM(Amount) AS amt
                FROM    Customer c
                JOIN    Account a
                ON      a.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
                JOIN    Payments p
                ON      p.AccountID = a.AccountID
                GROUP BY
                        YEAR(OpenedDate), MONTH(OpenedDate), AddressState
                )
        ) q
WHERE   rn = 1
```

Replace the last condition with `ORDER BY yr, mon, amt DESC` to get the list of all states like in your resultset:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  yr, mon, AddressState, amt, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY yr, mon, addressstate ORDER BY amt DESC) AS rn
        FROM    (
                SELECT  YEAR(OpenedDate) AS yr, MONTH(OpenedDate) AS mon, AddressState, SUM(Amount) AS amt
                FROM    Customer c
                JOIN    Account a
                ON      a.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
                JOIN    Payments p
                ON      p.AccountID = a.AccountID
                GROUP BY
                        YEAR(OpenedDate), MONTH(OpenedDate), AddressState
                )
        ) q
ORDER BY
        yr, mon, amt DESC
```

Comment: Looks good, just need to add SUM() around the Amount field in the SELECT

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    AddressState,
    year(OpenedDate) as Yr,
    month(OpenedDate) as Mnth,
    sum(Payment) as SumPayment
from Customer c
    inner join Account a
        on c.CustomerID=a.CustomerID
    inner join Payment p
        on a.AccountID=p.AccountID
group by AddressState, month(OpenedDate)
```